# How to update count of number of appended divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

I'm building a socket chat program, where everytime someone is joining the chat room, a badge showing the number of users, should increase.
The code below is the function that adds the new user's name to the list of users. The new name is added as a div with the id="elementInPeople. My problem is that the badge is only displaying 1, even though multiple users have entered the chat. Any suggestions to how I can fix this?

```
socket.on("update-people", function(people){
            $("#people").empty();
            $.each(people, function(clientid, name) {
                $people.append('<div id="elementInPeople">' + name + '</div>');
                var np = $("#elementInPeople").length;
                $("#numberOfPeopleOnline").text(np);
            });
    });
```

Server-side:

```
socket.on("connection", function(client) {
client.on("join", function(name){
    console.log("Someone joined the chat");
    people[client.id] = name;
    client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have connected to the server. Join or create room to chat");
    socket.sockets.emit("update-people", people);
    client.broadcast.emit('updateToOthers', name + " has joined the server.");
});
```

Comment: Does everyone's badge say 1?

Comment: Only one div with `id` attribute "elementInPeople" should be in the result page to be valid html

Comment: You can't repeat ID's in a page...they are unique by definition. Count class instead ... and do it after loop completes,...no need to count every iteration

Comment: Are the divs appending as you expect?  Have you tried using a class instead of an id?  How about counting people rather than divs?  What does np look like?

Comment: Yep. I'm using websocket. And when I enter the chat program in different windows, the count is not updated. However, the name are updated on a list

Comment: All the divs are appending just fine. If I should be counting people, should I being doing it like this: var np = people.length;   ??

Comment: I've updated my question with server-side code. @charlietfl how would you add the count function to that?

Comment: You all the time have the `people` array... So you can get the total `people.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to search the dom for a quantity that is already available from the data.

It appears that `people` is an object so `Object.keys(people).length` can give you the count

```
socket.on("update-people", function(people){
        $(".people").empty();
        $.each(people, function(clientid, name) {
            $people.append('<div class="elementInPeople">' + name + '</div>');
        });
        var np = Object.keys(people).length;
        $("#numberOfPeopleOnline").text(np);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

`var np = $("#elementInPeople").length;`
This is your problem. for each element in array you have to add some common class name. Like:

```
$people.append('<div id="elementInPeople" class="countable_people">' + name + '</div>');
```

Then you can find number of people like this:

```
var np = $(".countable_people").length;
$("#numberOfPeopleOnline").text(np);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```js
socket.on("update-people", function(people){
            $(".people").empty();
            $.each(people, function(clientid, name) {
                $people.append('<div class="elementInPeople">' + name + '</div>');
            });
            var np = $(".elementInPeople").length;
            $("#numberOfPeopleOnline").text(np);
    });
```

Comment: no need to count them every iteration...that's a lot of needless dom searching

Comment: I did not think about it! you are right. Now edit the message.